# Remove command bar/folder band in Windows 8 explorer

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer

This one:

[image]

I've seen guides for Windows 7 [here](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-make-folder-band-auto-hidden-in-windows-vista/), but it doesn't seem to work on Windows 8.

Comment: Just curious, why would you like to remove it?

Comment: it's big and pretty much useless

Comment: Hmmm, then you must be having a small screen! ;)

Comment: haha, not really, but I like to keep a lot of stuff on the screen at once, in small windows, so it takes up a good chunk of it.

Answer (score -1):

you can replace `shellstyle.dll` to hide command bar, to do so, download it [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/zci54ibe878m88l/shellstyle.dll), works on my win8.1

I've made a small change to it, it's based on the drakulaboy's [dll](http://www.eightforums.com/customization/47663-windows-8-1-shellstyle-dll-auto-hide-command-bar.html)

just go to `C:\Windows\Resources\Themes\(your theme folder)(aero is default)\Shell\NormalColor\`
backup your `shellstyle.dll` and replace it with the modded one

then reboot or log off/on

ok, sorry for improper form:

win7 tutorials say `www.askvg.com/how-to-make-folder-band-auto-hidden-in-windows-vista/` (sorry I can't post more than 2 links) you have to edit `shellstyle.dll` using Resource Hacker, when you open it go to `UIFILE -> 1 -> 1033` and after line `<style resid="FolderBandStyle">` add `<Element padding="rect(0rp,0rp,0rp,-28rp)"/>` than compile it, save it and replace it

the problem is I didn't find that line in win8.1's `shellstyle.dll`, but I found the drakulaboy's dll and changed it there and it's working now, the only thing is, that he uses the autohide feature which is this line `<if mousefocused="false" mousewithin="false"><Element padding="rect(0rp,0rp,0rp,-28rp)"/></if>` so you have to replace it with (as mentioned earlier) with this line `<Element padding="rect(0rp,0rp,0rp,-28rp)"/>` (you can replace `-28rp` with `-32rp`, I've read somewhere it's better)

hope it's more clear now
(sorry for my english, not a native speaker)

Comment: Even if your intentions are good, linking to and recommending the replacement of `dll`s isn't best practice. How can we verify your (and drakulaboy's) modifications?

Comment: (Perhaps you could edit your post to include information on how the modification was made)

Comment: Yeah, And if the mediafire answer goes down, your answer is entirely useless.